# Opacity not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to set up opacity on a div but its not working as expected.

https://jsfiddle.net/std0tgsy/1/

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  haveaccount" style="opacity: 2;text-align: center;" >
  <h2>JOIN US AT START HERE, GO PLACES.</h2>
  <p>Sign up here, create your account, and we'll follow up with you to complete your profile. You'll 
  <br> have access to our tools  and can expect to receive some
  <br> freebies along the way, Welcome!</p>
```

Comment: how do you expect??

Comment: Something like this -- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_opacity

Comment: Opacity runs from 0-1. `opacity: 2` is invalid

Comment: Changing the value, I see no difference.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Comment: Really? I do. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/std0tgsy/2/

Comment: So @user1050619 what did you change it too that it is not working?

Comment: @j08591: Thanks its working..

Comment: check your inner style of div element,you specify it 2, change it to value between 0~1.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

or

```
<div style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
   <div>
      Text added.
   </div>
</div>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp &
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="opacity: 2"; >
```

### JOIN US AT START HERE, GO PLACES.

OR

```
<h2 style="opacity:0.2">JOIN US AT START HERE, GO PLACES.</h2>
```

also u can do external css file.

[Visit](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)